# div has no content?

Tags: css

I'm still learning CSS, so please pardon me if this is something that is easily solved or taught in a class or book.

Here's what I see:
[image]

The two gray boxes are placeholders for image files further up the page. Those live in a different div that closes out before reaching the footer div. The source for the footer is:

```
<div id="footer"> 
  <div class="column"> 
    Column 1<br> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> 

    <br><br> 

    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
  </div> 

  <div class="column"> 
    Column 2<br> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> 

    <br><br> 

    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
    <a href="#">link</a> <br/> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the footer:

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #B0C4D1;
    padding-left: 8%;
}

.column {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

So if I make `min-height` long enough, then the blue covers all of the links in the footer, which is good. But I'd like to understand why I would need to do that. Why don't the columns in the footer div qualify as content so that the background gets filled up? If someone would link me to the relevant terms/tutorials explaining this, I'd really appreciate it. I'm having trouble coming up with the right words to find my answer.

Comment: To explain why: floated elements are removed from the normal flow and that is why the parent div does not expand to contain that element(s). The same is true for absolutely positioned elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floated elements collapse. Add overflow: hidden to your #footer. Example with your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/5HcG9/

Comment: So, how come overflow:hidden works? When I read the definition for it, I assumed that it wouldn't solve my problem because it would just hide my columns. Why, in this case, does it expand to contain them?

Answer (score 4):

add: `overflow: hidden;` to `#footer`

this will make the footer become a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) so it will contain its floated child columns

#### added relevant deatils from above link

> Floats, absolutely positioned
> elements, block containers (such as
> inline-blocks, table-cells, and
> table-captions) that are not block
> boxes, **and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible'** (except when that
> value has been propagated to the
> viewport) establish new block
> formatting contexts for their
> contents.
>
> ...
>
> In a block formatting context, each
> box's left outer edge touches the left
> edge of the containing block (for
> right-to-left formatting, right edges
> touch). **This is true even in the presence of floats** ....

in short as long as element only contains floated children, it will not know it's got content unless you tell it, more commonly known as "clearing floats" there are other solutions available too

Comment: I'm partial to answers with jsfiddle. :P

Comment: no worries rachel :) - I decided to go get the link for the block formatting context explanation instead this time as you asked about "taught in class"

Comment: @Rachel Lopes have updated my answer with the relevant bit which hopefully helps explain why `overflow` is one of the solutions to making an element contain floats, in answer to your question on @jackrugile's answer

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on clearing floats. 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your div `#footer` to grow automatically, it should float just like the divs it contains. The other option would be to add another div that does not float and has `clear: both` set.

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #B0C4D1;
    padding-left: 8%;
    float: left;
    width: 92%; /* Together with padding-left it's exactly 100% */
}
```